# Test reports is missing in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, junit, automated-tests, junit5

When my build failed - test report is missing in Jenkins. What do I do wrong? 
This is part of my jenkinsfile:

```
node {
    stage('Integration tests') {
        git url: "https://$autotestsGitRepo", branch: 'develop',credentialsId: gitlabCredentialsId

    sh 'chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew  clean test 
                step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults:'build/test-results/test/*.xml'])
             }
        }
```

**This is my jenkins output:**

> 5 tests completed, 5 failed
>
> > Task :test FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':test'.
>
>   > There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///var/jenkins_home/workspace/test2/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s 4 actionable tasks: 4 executed [Pipeline] }
>   [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // node [Pipeline] End of
>   Pipeline ERROR: script returned exit code 1 Finished: FAILURE

Comment: What's in file:///var/jenkins_home/workspace/test2/build/reports/tests/test/index.html?